# How to disable "Request Signatures" notification in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Every time I open up a PDF in Adobe Acrobat 2021 I get a notification asking me to request signatures.

I don't know what this is or why it's there and I can't figure out how to disable it.

I have read through the [feature lockdown](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/FeatureLockdown.html) options and tried disabling all of the signature services with no change:

```
"bToggleAdobeSign"=dword:00000001
"bToggleFSSSignatureSaving"=dword:00000001
"bToggleManageSign"=dword:00000001
```

How do I disable this notification?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to disable “Verify signatures when the document is opened”?

Comment: Yes. I disabled this option as well and there was no change.

Answer (score -2):

This is marketing blurb by Adobe for their Signature services. You can simply ignore it. I'd have to look around where to disable it.